# How to change volume of an audio AVPacket

Tags: qt, ffmpeg

I have a desktop Qt-based application that fetches a sound stream from the network and plays it using `QAudioOutput`. I want to provide a volume control to the user so that he can reduce the volume. My code looks like this:

```
float volume_control = get_user_pref(); // user provided volume level {0.0,1.0}

for (;;) {
    AVPacket *retrieved_pkt = get_decoded_packet_stream();  // from network stream

    AVPacket *work_pkt
       = change_volume(retrieved_pkt, volume_control); // this is what I need

    // remaining code to play the work_pkt ...
}
```

How do I implement `change_volume()` or is there any off the shelf function that I can use?

Edit: Adding codec-related info as requested in the comments

```
QAudioFormat format;
format.setFrequency(44100);
format.setChannels(2);
format.setSampleSize(16);
format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
```

Comment: is the packet containing pcm data? does `0 < volume_control < 1` means the volume can only be reduced??

Comment: I am not sure if the data is PCM. How do I find out?

Comment: Though I want to reduce the volume in this particular case, I would be interested in a generic solution that does both (increase and decrease).

Comment: to find you need to known codec used in `get_decoded_packet_stream()`. The codec will specify the output format. To decrease the volume `volume_control` need to take values > 0.

Comment: In general, the `AVPacket` contains compressed data. You have to decode the packet by corresponding audio decoder, then apply the change volume of each audio sample and then re-encode the packet if necessary.

Comment: @UmNyobe Found the codec info. Yes, it's PCM. I have updated the question with other related info - sample size, endian-ness channels, freq etc.

Comment: @pogorskiy According to [this article](http://www.ypass.net/blog/2010/01/pcm-audio-part-3-basic-audio-effects-volume-control), it seems for PCM audio, we can just multiply the data with a constant to control its volume. To avoid reinventing, is there an off-the-shelf routine I can use? I am worried if I have to code this myself using a for-loop around a multiplication, it might get inefficient

Comment: nope it is just as simple for pcm. Follow the directions in your article. You can save decoded audio as `.wav` following the format spec (basic header then data) in order to test the changes, or encode it back.

Comment: @UmNyobe Thanks for the pointer. Will try. Any caveat w.r.t handling channels I should be aware of upfront? The article does not talk about channels at all. At any rate, I shall investigate and keep updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works just fine.

```
// audio_buffer is a byte array of size data_size 
// volume_level is a float between 0 (silent) and 1 (original volume)

int16_t * pcm_data  = (int16_t*)(audio_buffer);
int32_t pcmval;
for (int ii = 0; ii < (data_size / 2); ii++) {   // 16 bit, hence divided by 2
    pcmval = pcm_data[ii] * volume_level ;
    pcm_data[ii] = pcmval;
}
```

Edit: I think there is a significant scope of optimization here, since my solution is compute-intensive. I guess `avcodec_decode_audio()` can be used to speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a working sample

```
QByteArray decreaseVolume(const QByteArray& audioData, qreal volumeLevel)
{
    QByteArray modifiedAudioData(audioData.size(), '\0');

    for (int i = 0; i < (audioData.size() / 2); i++)
    {
        int16_t sample = qFromLittleEndian<int16_t>(audioData.mid(i * 2, 2));
        int32_t modifiedSample = sample * volumeLevel;
        QByteArray modifiedBytes = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&modifiedSample), 2);
        modifiedAudioData.replace(i * 2, 2, modifiedBytes);
    }

    return modifiedAudioData;
}
```